# Make slider call knockout js function on change

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

, I have a slider on my html page which has a databind to an observable.
Like this.

```
<input id="ex2" data-slider-id="ex2Slider" type="text" data-bind="sliderValue: {value: borrowOrInvestAmount, min:0, max: 5000, step: 1, formatter:formatter2}"
        style="display: none;">
```

And as well as I have a table which shows interest like this.

```
<td <input data-bind=" valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"><input data-bind="value: amount1"/></td>
```

Basically what I want is that, when I change the value on the slider, it should call this function which takes in value from the observable borrowOrInvestAmount 
and should return the interest rate which will be put into the observable and shown on the table. And each time the slider value changes it should call this function again.

```
function DoBusinessViewModel(root) {
            var self = this;
            self.items = ko.observableArray();
            self.itemsNotFoundMsg = ko.observable(null);
            var borrowOrInvestAmount_tmp = 0;
            var moneyBorrOrInvUri;
            if (root.boolInvestments()) {
                moneyBorrOrInvUri = BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/SearchRequestsOrInvestments/' + auth + '/' + root.borrowOrInvestAmount() + '/' + root.borrowOrInvestCurrency() + '/' + 0 + '/' + 1;
            } else {
                moneyBorrOrInvUri = BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/SearchRequestsOrInvestments/' + auth + '/' + root.borrowOrInvestAmount() + '/' + root.borrowOrInvestCurrency() + '/' + 0 + '/' + 0;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: moneyBorrOrInvUri,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function(BorrowOrInvestDetails) {
               $.each(BorrowOrInvestDetails, function (index, item) {
                   self.items.push(item);
/* here is where I am trying to get the value of interest from  for the table*/
                   self.interest(self.item()[0].Interest);

                   borrowOrInvestAmount_tmp += parseFloat(item.borrowOrInvestAmount);
                   /* If we are reading borrowing request and thee are any requests with payment_term = 2 = Monthly,
                    * we must set root.paymentTerm observable to 2 = Monthly. */
                   if (!root.boolInvestments()) {
                       if (item.payment_term == 2) {
                           if (root.paymentTerm() == 1) {
                                root.paymentTerm(2);
                           } 
                       }
                   }
                });
                root.borrowOrInvestAmount(borrowOrInvestAmount_tmp.toFixed(2));
                root.borrowOrInvestAbbreviation(self.items()[0].Abbreviation);
                if (root.boolInvestments()) {
                    root.getFee(root.borrowOrInvestAmount(), root.borrowOrInvestCurrency(), 'money_request', 'borrow');
                } else {
                    root.getFee(root.borrowOrInvestAmount(), root.borrowOrInvestCurrency(), 'money_offer', 'invest');
                }
                root.getPaymentPlanForMultibleItems(self.items());


            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                self.itemsNotFoundMsg(errorThrown);
            })
            .always(function(data){               
            });   
        };
```

Since I added the value borrowOrInvestAmount to the slider I Am not sure if its actually calling the dobusinessfunction. Dont know what I am missing.

Comment: Please put some extra work in the code you've posted. There's syntax errors, missing bits (e.g. where's the custom binding handler), superfluous bits (e.g. is (all) that ajax code truly relevant?), code commented out, etc.

Comment: If i understood your problem correctly, you can either subscribe to the slider value and do your updates in the function, or make the value that depends on the slider value a computed observable.

Comment: @Jeroen I dont think there is syntax error since the code works , and yea alot of things are not relevant but I just put it there to make it clear, but please do help me if you know how to

Comment: @HotTowelie but for now its not calling the dobusiness function with the observable value ..

Comment: Does your borrowOrInvestAmount observable work as intended? If so, try something like: self.amount1 = ko.computed(function(){ return borrowOrInvestAmount() * someInterestOrWhatever });

Comment: @HotTowelie yup that works, the sliders changes and gets value but the value doesnt call the do function which needs to get the interest rate for that amount

Comment: @MasnadNihit `<td <input data-bind=" valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">` that's invalid syntax AFAIK.

Comment: I accidentaly posted half of my comment the first time :) try putting the call into the computed function. It should call the function every time the borrowOrInvestAmount updates. Also, I'd consider using Q for asynch calls and Durandal for lifecycle events, makes things much more elegant for me.

Comment: See "[mcve]" for guidance on creating a good repro.

Comment: @Jeroen sorry i forgot to paste the closing tag for td, and yea I will keep in mind  that I need to write better codes, but for this example I just need to update the observable and should call do businessmodel at the same time to get interest its data